# how to pass a string from broadcastReceiver class to another activity

Tags: android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Ciao a tutti !!
i almost give up. 
my app uses a datepicker to set a date ,for each date i set an alarm. 
My boadcastreceiver class receives an intent too .

here my code :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


     String dato;





    public Context context;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {





            dato=intent.getStringExtra("nome");
            //intent.putExtra("nome", dato);



            Toast toast =Toast.makeText(context, "Oggi e' il compleanno di  " + dato , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
             toast.show();

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.example.memopad", "com.example.memopad.CustomDialogActivity");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("nome",dato);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            context.startActivity(i);







}




    }
```

when the alarm fires, CustomDialogActivity starts and a toast is launched 
i would like to use the string dato not only in the tosat but aven in the CustomDialogActivity

see the following code related to CustomDialogActivity :

p

```
ublic class CustomDialogActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    TextView TextViewDialog ;
    ImageView ImageViewCumple;
    Button ButtonRitorna;
    String dato1;
    Intent intent;
    Bundle bundle;






    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.customdialoglayout);

        TextViewDialog=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.datacumple50);
        ImageViewCumple = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
        ImageViewCumple = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ButtonRitorna =(Button)findViewById(R.id.tornaBirthDay);

        ButtonRitorna.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent ( CustomDialogActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        //dato1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nome"); 
        //dato1=intent.getStringExtra("nome");
        //TextViewDialog.setText(dato1);

        bundle=intent.getExtras();
        TextViewDialog.setText(" Oggi e' il compleanno di " + bundle);

}
```

Could you give me any hints?

Please !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While setting the text to TextViewDialog, use the following to get the text that was passed in the bundle.
getIntent().getStringExtra("nome")
I was able to print it in the toast as well as in the activity.